# Multi-Core microcontroller eval boards?

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, development, development-tools

Seeing as there are more and more mutli-core processors systems. I'd like to learn more about them.

What mutli-core microcontroller eval boards exist, if any?

Thanks

Comment: Parallax propeller is great, are there any ARM core boards too?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I like the [Propeller from Parallax](http://www.parallax.com/propeller/). Quite a few dev boards available in the store.

Propeller is a simple 8-core microcontroller with 32 kB of shared RAM and 2 kB of RAM per core. Runs at up to 80 MHz and has 32 I/O pins.

Comment: I was about to post the same thing. Propeller is a simple 8-core microcontroller with 32 kB of shared RAM and 2 kB of RAM per core. Runs at up to 80 MHz and has 32 I/O pins.

Comment: I have a Propeller Board of Education that I have yet to crack open and play with... need (1) more free time, (2) a compelling reason for 8 MCUs...

Comment: @vicatcu Here's another reason to add to the list: We do everything in software! ideology. It's a bit different user experience having to do absolutely everything in software, since the part has no hardware peripherals, except for two counters per core.

Answer (score 8):

XMos have quite a good range too. Here is their [About page](https://www.xmos.com/origins/) and some [processors](https://www.xmos.com/processor-catalogue/).

Some of their [development boards](https://www.xmos.com/products/xkits) are very reasonably priced too.

Answer (score 3):

Freescale i.MX6 on the [Nitrogen6X](http://boundarydevices.com/products/nitrogen6x-board-imx6-arm-cortex-a9-sbc/) Dev Board from Boundary Devices. It's a quad-core ARM Cortex A9 processor. Or if you don't care about Wifi, the [SabreLite](http://boundarydevices.com/products/sabre-lite-imx6-sbc/) is a bit cheaper. I'm not sure this is in bounds for what your asking because you said microcontroller (and this is decidedly a microprocessor, if you're into religion).

Answer (score 3):

[Panda board](http://pandaboard.org/) is a very nice board from TI that has a lot going for it and is multicore:

Comment: It must be a good board if there is a waiting list to get one.  I like that is has support for Jelly bean too.

Comment: I read some rumours of TI stopping development of the OMAP processor line...

Comment: It's true that they're stopping focus on the OMAP for Tablets and phones, but they're still going after the embedded market, so that doesn't mean they won't support. Maybe they won't develop as much. Still, the board has a large community around it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of demo boards for the [LPC4350](http://www.nxp.com/products/microcontrollers/cortex_m4/#demoboards). It's a Cortex M4 and Cortex M0 on a single chip running at the same clock speed with a shared memory space for message passing. The general idea is that you can use the M0 to handle all of the I/O and use the more powerful math capabilities of the M4 for all of your signal processing/computational needs.